# How many values of $\theta$ give $cos(\theta)$ is algebraic

Tags: transcendental-numbers

I recently saw Lindemann's proof that $\pi$ is transcendental by using the fact that $e^{i\pi} = -1$, and this made me realize that the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem implies that the $\cos$ , $\sin$  of all rational angles is transcendental.

Do we know anything about the other direction, that is, which transcendental numbers give algebraic answers for the trig functions.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try using the intermediate value theorem - what is the image of $\cos$ and $\sin$?

Comment: The intermediate value theorem would suggest that for every algebraic number $\in [-1,1] \exists$ corresponding transcendental numebr , but the only way I can think to represent them would be to use arcsin or arccos, is there anything I should research to better understand what these arcsin or arccos transcendental numbers represent beyond being the inverse sin or cos functions, if there is anything to be understood there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much depth to offer here, but I do find the question quite engaging; so I fooled around with it for awhile and was able to affirm my hunch that, at the very least, the cosine of any rational multiple of $\pi$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$; the calcuations are pretty simple though a little "grungy"; here's what I've got:

Set

$\theta = \dfrac{p \pi}{q}, \; 0 \ne p, 0 < q \in \Bbb Z; \tag 1$

then

$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta = \cos \left (\dfrac{p \pi}{q} \right ) + i \sin \left ( \dfrac{p \pi}{q} \right ); \tag 2$

$(e^{i\theta})^q = e^{iq \theta} = \cos q \theta + i \sin q \theta$
$= \cos q \left ( \dfrac{p \pi}{q} \right ) + i \sin q \left ( \dfrac {p \pi}{q} \right ) = \cos p \pi + i \sin p \pi = (-1)^p; \tag 3$

$(e^{i\theta})^q = (\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)^q =  \displaystyle \sum_0^q i^{k}\dfrac{q!}{k!(q - k)!} \cos^{q - k} \theta  \sin^k \theta; \tag 4$

we may break this sum into two sums, over even and odd $k$, which are then its real (even) and imaginary (odd) parts; we will effect this operation by introducing a new index $j$ such that

$\displaystyle \sum_0^q i^{k}\dfrac{q!}{k!(q - k)!} \cos^{q - k} \theta  \sin^k \theta = \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j \le q} i^{2j} \dfrac{q!}{(2j)!(q - 2j)!} \cos^{q - 2j} \theta  \sin^{2j} \theta$
$+ \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j + 1 \le q} i^{2j + 1} \dfrac{q!}{(2j + 1)!(q - 2j - 1)!} \cos^{q - 2j - 1} \theta  \sin^{2j + 1} \theta; \tag 5$

since $i^{2j} = (-1)^j$ and $i^{2j + 1} = (-1)^j i$, the sums on the right may be re-written and we have

$(e^{i\theta})^q = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j \le q} (-1)^j \dfrac{q!}{(2j)!(q - 2j)!} \cos^{q - 2j} \theta  \sin^{2j} \theta$
$+  \displaystyle i \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j + 1 \le q} (-1)^j \dfrac{q!}{(2j + 1)!(q - 2j - 1)!} \cos^{q - 2j - 1} \theta  \sin^{2j + 1} \theta; \tag 6$

we see from (3),

$(e^{i\theta})^q = (-1)^p, \tag 7$

that $(e^{i\theta})^q$ is real; therefore, the second sum on the right of (6) vanishes; being a real multiple of $i$, this entire sum represents the imaginary part of $(e^{i\theta})^q$; we therefore need not deal further with this second sum, and will from here on only focus on the first, which is the real part of $(e^{i\theta})^q$; thus,

$(e^{i\theta})^q = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j \le q} (-1)^j \dfrac{q!}{(2j)!(q - 2j)!} \cos^{q - 2j} \theta  \sin^{2j} \theta = (-1)^p; \tag 8$

our next step is to use the identity

$\sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta \tag 9$

to eliminate the $\sin^{2j} \theta$ factors in (8), replacing them by

$\sin^{2j} \theta = (\sin^2 \theta)^j = (1 - \cos^2 \theta)^j, \tag{10}$

whence

$(e^{i\theta})^q = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j \le q} (-1)^j \dfrac{q!}{(2j)!(q - 2j)!} (\cos^{q - 2j} \theta) (1 - \cos^2 \theta)^j = (-1)^p, \tag{11}$

or

$(e^{i\theta})^q - (-1)^p = \left (\displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j \le q} (-1)^j \dfrac{q!}{(2j)!(q - 2j)!} (\cos^{q - 2j} \theta) (1 - \cos^2 \theta)^j \right ) + (-1)^{p + 1} = 0, \tag{12}$

which shows that $\cos \theta = \cos (p\pi / q)$ satisfies the polynomial

$P_{p, \; q}[x] =  \left (\displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^{ 2j \le q} (-1)^j \dfrac{q!}{(2j)!(q - 2j)!} x^{q - 2j} (1 - x^2)^j \right ) + (-1)^{p +1} \in \Bbb Q[x], \tag{13}$

and is hence algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.  In fact, it is easy to see that the  coefficients of $P_{p, \; q}[x]$ are integers, so that indeed

$P_{p,\; q}[x] \in \Bbb Z[x]. \tag{14}$

Now it should come as no surprise that the "results" derived here are well-known, and deeply analyzed; see [this wikipedia article on Chebyshev_polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).